# Extensão para melhorar a produtividade do Atom

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma ferramenta que fornece essas funções no Atom editor ou Atom IDE?
[image: Instância de um método no PHPstorm na assitatura]
[image: Instância do método com tolltype]

Essas funções me ajudam na produtividade do dia a dia!

Comment: Qual função? autocompletar? o threeview de arquivos?

Comment: A função que eu busco é que mostra as assinaturas do método... através de tolltype, ou semelhante a primeira imagem, onde o método já esta pronto!

Comment: Não relacionado à dúvida da pergunta, sugiro usar "financeiro" no lugar de "finaceiro", para ficarem iguais tanto a função quanto a variável.

Comment: Então... @Bacco ... isso foi somente um exemplo rápido para mostrar a funcionalidade que estou em busca!

Answer (score 0):

tem o pacote ide-php, ele suporta a linguagem PHP para Atom-IDE, mas você também deve instalar o pacote atom-ide-ui para expor a funcionalidade dentro do Atom.

[Aqui está o link do pacote ide-php](https://atom.io/packages/ide-php)

[E aqui está o link do pacote atom-ide-ui](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-ui)

Obs: Quando abrir a página, é só clicar em install, que ele vai abrir um alerte pedindo para abrir o Atom, clica em abrir e quando abrir o Atom é só clicar em install novamente.